# Azure Logic App File System Connector on DFS

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We see the [Does logic app file system connector work with DFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62507317/does-logic-app-file-system-connector-work-with-dfs) (but cannot add any comment to get the latest news on this topic)

=> Does logic app file system connector work now with DFS (Distributed file system) ?
We still have the error on our side :
"status": 400,
"message": "The requested action could not be completed. Check your request parameters to make sure the path...

Regards,
A.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [Logic App connector document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/connector-reference/connector-reference-logicapps-connectors) DFS file system connector is still not supported in the logic app.

For more information, We would suggest you to raise a request over [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/) platform or reach out to support by raising a support ticket from portal.